# Configuring VPN (AnyConnect, OpenVPN)

Tags: linux, vpn

I'm trying to connect to an AnyConnect VPN server on my FC30 machine. I have the AnyConnect configuration to connect a MacOS device. I just don't have AnyConnect on my FC 30 device.

I tried to download AnyConnect, but it's not like there's a simple "AnyConnect Client" package to download. Do I get the Pre-Deployment pacakge, the Headend Deployment Package, or something else?

My question is two part. If you think it's easier to use AnyConnect, which AnyConnect package or packages should I download? If you think it's easier to use OpenVPN, what parts of the AnyConnect configuration should I port over?

Answer (score 1):

I use `openconnect` to connect to our AnyConnect VPN.

```
○ → apt search ^openconnect
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done

openconnect/focal,now 8.05-1 amd64 [installed]
  open client for Cisco AnyConnect, Pulse, GlobalProtect VPN
```

```
NAME
       openconnect - Multi-protocol VPN client, 
       for Cisco AnyConnect VPNs and others


DESCRIPTION
       The  program  openconnect  connects  to  VPN servers 
       which use standard TLS/SSL, DTLS, and ESP protocols for data
       transport.

       It was originally written to support Cisco "AnyConnect" VPN servers, 
       and has since been extended with  experimen‐
       tal  support  for  Juniper  Network Connect and Junos Pulse VPN servers
       (--protocol=nc) and PAN GlobalProtect VPN servers (--protocol=gp).
```

```
cat $HOME/.openconnect

user=knb
authgroup=EmployeesOrSimilar

sudo openconnect --config $HOME/.openconnect
# authdialogs appear, asking for sudo password, and then VPN password
```